# Iphone application not showing up in notification center

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I have developed an iphone application that uses local notifications, i submitted the app to the appstore and downloaded the app to my device, but the app doesn't showing up inside notification center(Settings->Notifications) is there's any settings needed to be configured while submitting the app to the appstore to allow that?
Note: i'm using ios 8.1.2,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific reason for this. Many of us face this problem due to change in provisioning profiles for the same app.

Just try below:

1. Delete your app and install again. check notification settings.
2. Reboot your phone. check notification settings.
3. Remove all provisioning profiles, remove app, install again. check notification settings.

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses **local** notifications only, then there will be no entry in the settings page. This one is dedicated to **remote** notifications using the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS).